# Template constructor is not considered

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

I'm implementing a version of std::experimental::observer_ptr with some own additions. I also want to add a constructor taking a std::unique_ptr. In addition, I want to be able to construct from convertible pointer types. Based on a similar example in the reference, this is what I came up with:

```
template <typename T>
class observer_ptr {
    // [...]
    template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>> = 0>
    observer_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<U>& ptr) noexcept : m_ptr(ptr.get()) {}
```

However, it looks like this template is never considered.

Here's a small working example. I also left in the other constructors that I have, because maybe these are causing a conflict when the compiler is deciding for the overload? The "Case II" on the bottom shows want I want to do and how it's not compiling.

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

// Exerpt from own observer_ptr implementation.
template <typename T>
class observer_ptr {
public:
    using element_type = T;

    // Constructors, following https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr/observer_ptr
    constexpr observer_ptr() noexcept : m_ptr(nullptr) {}
    constexpr observer_ptr(nullptr_t) noexcept : m_ptr(nullptr) {}
    explicit observer_ptr(element_type* ptr) noexcept : m_ptr(ptr) {}

    // I used this constructor from the reference as baseline for my addition.
    template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, element_type*>> = 0>
    observer_ptr(observer_ptr<U> other) noexcept : m_ptr(other.m_ptr) {}

    observer_ptr(const observer_ptr& other) = default;
    observer_ptr(observer_ptr&& other) = default;

    // --- Own addition: Construction from std::unique_ptr ---

    // This one is good enough for Case I.
    observer_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<T>& ptr) noexcept : m_ptr(ptr.get()) {}

    // This one should handle Case II. But I doesn't... why?
    template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, element_type*>> = 0>
    observer_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<U>& ptr) noexcept : m_ptr(ptr.get()) {}

private:
    T* m_ptr;
};

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

int main() {
    // Case I: Simple and easy
    auto owning_ptr1 = std::make_unique<int>(7);
    observer_ptr<int> obs_ptr1(owning_ptr1);

    // Case II: Convertible pointer types
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<Derived*, Base*>); // passes
    auto owning_ptr2 = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    observer_ptr<Base> obs_ptr2(owning_ptr2); // error C2664:
    // 'observer_ptr<Base>::observer_ptr(const observer_ptr<Base> &)': cannot convert argument 1
    // from 'std::unique_ptr<Derived,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'std::nullptr_t'
}
```

Bonus question: I this a dangerous constructor? E.g. is there a scenario where this leads to unwanted behavior, e.g. dangling pointer right after construction?

Comment: `std::enable_if_t<...>` expands to `void` on success, and `void = 0` is not a valid template parameter. Did you mean `std::enable_if_t<...> * = nullptr`? Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your templated constructor is incorrect, since the default type of `enable_if_t` is `void`, and you can't assign 0 to that.

You can fix it like this:

```
template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, element_type*>, int> = 0>
observer_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<U>& ptr) noexcept : m_ptr(ptr.get()) {}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/UNV94z).